# How to find whoch part of OR condition is met when you have 40 conditions in Unix

Tags: awk

I have a file which is having 40 fields and each should have particular length. I put a OR condition as below and checked if it is meeting the requirement and print something any of the field length is more than what is required. But I want to know and print which field exactly is more than what is required.

command:

```
awk -F "|" 'length ($1) > 10 || length ($2) > 30 || length ($3) > 50 || length ($4) > 15 ||...|| length ($40) > 55' /path/filename
```

Comment: Seperate them, into indivual checks, and do an echo

Comment: Is there any other way except separating them and do an echo?

Answer (score 1):

your existing code will not test all the conditions after the first resulting true, due to short circuiting. If you want to check them all, better to keep the size requirements in variable and loop through all fields, one example can be

```
$ awk -F'|' -v size="10|30|50..." '
              BEGIN{split(size,s)} 
                   {c=sep=""; 
                    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)  
                      if(length($i)>s[i]) {c=c sep i; sep=FS}; 
                    if(c) print $0,c}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to write too many field conditions manually. Since you haven't showed us the expected output then based on your statements following code is written.

```
awk -F"|" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(length($i)>40){print i,$i" having more than 40 length"}}}'  Input_file
```

Above will print a field number, field's value which is having length more than 40.

***EDIT:*** Adding an example on same, let's say following is the Input_file.

```
cat Input_file
vbrwvkjrwvbrwvbrwv123|vwkjrbvrwnbvrwvkbvkjrwbvbwvwbvrwbvrwbvvbjbvhjrwv|rwvirwvhbrwvbrwvbrwvbhrwbvhjrwbvhjrwbvjrwbvhjwbvhjvbrwvbrwhjvb
123|wwd|wfwcwc

awk -F"|" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(length($i)>40){print i,$i" having more than 40 length"}}}' file3499
2 vwkjrbvrwnbvrwvkbvkjrwbvbwvwbvrwbvrwbvvbjbvhjrwv having more than 40 length
3 rwvirwvhbrwvbrwvbrwvbhrwbvhjrwbvhjrwbvjrwbvhjwbvhjvbrwvbrwhjvb having more than 40 length
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same as karakfa's answer, just ... more whitespacey

```
awk -F "|" '
    BEGIN {
        max[1] = 10
        max[2] = 30
        max[3] = 50
        max[4] = 15
        # ...
        max[40] = 55
    }
    {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            if (length($i) > max[i]) {
                printf "Error: line %d, column %d is wider than %d\n", NR, i, max[i]
            }
        }
    }
' file
```